# How to tell Rails to bypass a parameter filter logging in a particular log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used Rails [filter parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html) to not print out the cities and States in the logs.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:city, :state]
```

However, I have a custom log that is getting incorrectly filtered and I need it to get printed:

```
Rails.logger.info("Transaction state has changed.", state: transaction.state)
```

How can I force this hash to bypass the parameter filtering?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a way to ignore specific filters, however you can make the filter less generic. They are more generic than it seems.

---

Each entry in `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters` is actually an argument to [`ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter.new`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/ParameterFilter.html#method-c-new).

This takes two types of filters: Regexes and Proc. Everything else is converted to a Regex.

`Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:city, :state]` is really the very generic `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [/city/i, /state/i]`. That will match `state_of_mind` and `specificity` which is probably not what you had in mind.

```
pf = ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter.new([:city, :state])
p pf.filter({specificity: 42, state_of_mind: "confused"})

# {:specificity=>"[FILTERED]", :state_of_mind=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

---

You can match specific models with `model.param`.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += ["user.city", "user.state"]
```

This will match `{ user: { state: "..."} }` (`user.state`) and not `{ transaction: { state: "..." } }` (`transaction.state`).

However, these are still unanchored regex matches, so it *will match* `{ admin_user: { state_of_mind: "..." } }` (`admin_user.state_of_mind`).

To avoid this, use a full regex.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [/^user\.(city|state)$/]
```

---

You can also use a function for more control. This takes the key, value, and original parameters. These are a bit awkward.

- The "key" is only the immediate key so `{ transaction: { state: "..." } }` will only get `:state`.
- The value itself must be changed.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters << ->(key,value,original_params) do
  p key
  p value
  p original_params
  v.replace("[FILTERED]") if key.to_s.match(/^(city|state)$/i)?
end
```

Comment: This is great information! So there's no way to just filter it out for a specific log? Is there a hack I could do like `status: #{transaction.state.capitalize}` or anything like that you can think of?

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon I'm not aware of a way to override the parameter filtering. One "hack" would be to use `province` to mean "subdivision of a country". `state` is pretty US specific. Then [localize it into US English](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). Or you can rename your `transaction.state` to something like `status`. In general, don't trust column names to mean the same thing across tables.

Comment: Thanks! with `status: transaction.state` the param is not filtered anymore. If you update the answer to include this I mark it as the answer since your current solution also works